# webpack : The term 'webpack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I want to create a new project with webpack and typescript. I created project and webpack file, I also installed webpack using

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

as mentioned in webpack website and it install webpack successfully,
but when I type webpack on my command line I see this error:

```
webpack : The term 'webpack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ webpack
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webpack:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing webpack as a part of a project does not make it available globally.

## Fix

If you want to run globally you can install it globally:

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I had to install webpack according to babel-loader website (see https://github.com/babel/babel-loader):

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

Which installed these values in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    // ...
  },
```